# How do I reset user to default settings

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, home-directory

Long story short, I accidentally ran `sudo rm -rf ~` and as a result removed most of my home directory. In a panicked state, and with a bit of research, I attempted to recover what I could with extundelete, which has recovered some files.

That aside I have 'lost' the usual files in the home directory, I only have the Downloads folder left and since I didn't have anything too vital stored in the other directories I would like to restore them if at all possible.

I have looked in the file ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs and I have the following:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

All I want is to restore those folders and all system settings back to default, but I don't want to re-install Ubuntu as I don't want to lose any software I have down loaded.

At this point any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

J

Update:

I have created another admin user and everything works as it did previously leading me to believe that this is a local user issue, I am going to attempt to analyse the difference in the files between the two accounts and see if I get any improvements, update to come.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, those folders get re-created upon every reboot. As for re-setting system settings back to default, you might be a little more specific on which settings you want to be restored.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case here, I have just rebooted and still none of the folders are there, I have Desktop and Downloads but that is it, no Music, Pictures, Videos etc. I just want to get everything back to the 'default'

Answer (score 8):

You may want to copy the files from /etc/skel.

```
cp -rT /etc/skel/ "$HOME"
```

Those are the files which every newly created user starts with in the HOME folder, and are sufficient to be able to log in.

Comment: Gunnar, can you explain the reasoning behind copying files from `/etc/skel` ? what exactly that does ? in other words add more info please

Comment: @Serg: Ok, done.

Comment: Gunnar, Thanks for the answer, the terminal now displays the colour indicators on the type of file/directory. However I still can't restore the missing folders in the user-dirs.dirs /etc/skel/ only had examples.desktop in the folder

Comment: @J.Evason: Try the command `xdg-user-dirs-update --force` (see [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html)).

Answer (score 3):

First, log out and login by console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then backup & remove user settings (ignore warnings about `".."` being busy):

```
 mkdir ~/old && mv ~/.* ~/old/
```

Copy default user files:

```
cp -rT /etc/skel/ "$HOME"
```

Type `exit`, return to graphic mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and login again.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I was able fixed it.
It should be done for a particular user.

Log into Terminal via user you want to reconfigure default directory.

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

The above command will force to reconfigure the directory and it will update the config at `user-dirs.dirs` folder located at `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

After doing this, it is suggested to ***reboot the system*** or reload gnome(Type **r** after **ALT + F2**) so that these recreated directories paths get configured for other processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a managed to resolve the issue of the missing folders in nautilus by copying the .config file of a newly created user into my other home directory. I also had an issue of apps not unlocking from the launcher that was resolved my removing the zeitgeist folder and restarting the computer, thanks for everyone's help!